# How should I close and open Card component in framework7 (react)?

Tags: reactjs, html-framework-7

I have created card with framework7 card components, I manipulate props, tested events, but I just couldnt open and close my card, I really need help to close and open card component of framework7

I checked all the props and events but It didnt work, even my onClickHandler didnt work...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example